# unordered_map giving Segmentation fault (core dumped) when calling C++ library from python

Tags: python, c++

i am trying to use https://github.com/Spyros-DC/words-in-some-editdistance/blob/master/my_distance.cpp C++ implementation in python, however i kept receiving Segmentation fault (core dumped). Below is the entire code in python and C++, i have edited small parts of the original library to suit my use case. I have managed to find that when trying to use the unordered_map ***children.count(remaining_w.at(0))*** it is throwing the segmentation fault error. I was wondering if anyone knows what is causing the error. Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
// using namespace std::chrono;

class trie{
    public:
        string word;
        unordered_map<char, trie*> children;

        // this function works
        // with the argument flag set to zero
        int insert(string w, int flag, string remaining_w = ""){  
            //the first time we call insert
            if(flag == 0)
                remaining_w = w;
            int the_size = remaining_w.size();

            if(children.count(remaining_w.at(0)) == 0){
                children[remaining_w.at(0)] = new trie();
    
            }
            if(the_size == 0){
            word = w;
            return 0;
            }else{
            //the recursive calls with flag one
            children[remaining_w.at(0)]->insert(w, 1, remaining_w.erase(0, 1));
            return 0;
            }
        }
};

class AutoCorrect{

    public:
        // The tree
        trie tree;
        //the dictionary with the words
        const int max_cost = 2;
        const int too_big_distance = 10;

        void insert(char* word){
            
            ifstream ifp(word);
            
            while(ifp >> word){
                cout << word <<endl;
                tree.insert(word, 0);
        // }
        }

        }

        void test(char* test){
            cout << test << endl;        
        }

        void search_recursive(trie* p_tree, char ch, const string& word, vector<int>& previous_row, int max_cost, unordered_map <string, int>& results)
        {
            int sz = previous_row.size();
            int min_row = 12;
        
            vector<int> current_row(sz, too_big_distance);
            current_row[0] = previous_row[0] + 1;
        
            // Calculate the min cost of insertion, deletion, match or substution
            int insert_or_del, replace;
            for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
                insert_or_del = min(current_row[i-1] + 1, previous_row[i] + 1);
                replace = (word[i-1] == ch) ? previous_row[i-1] : (previous_row[i-1] + 1);
        
                current_row[i] = min(insert_or_del, replace);
            }
        

            if ((current_row[sz-1] <= max_cost) && (p_tree->word != "")) {
            results[p_tree->word] = current_row[sz-1];
            }

            for(auto& it: current_row){
                if (it < min_row)
                    min_row = it;
            }
            if(min_row <= max_cost){
                for(auto& it: p_tree->children){
                    search_recursive(it.second, it.first, word, current_row, max_cost, results);
            }
            }
            
        }


        int search(string word)
        {
            unordered_map <string, int> results;
                
            int sz = word.size();
            
            vector<int> current_row(sz + 1);
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= sz; ++i){ 
                current_row[i] = i;
            }
            
            for(auto& it: tree.children){
                search_recursive(it.second, it.first, word, current_row, max_cost, results);
            }

            for(auto& p:results)
                cout << p.first << ", " << p.second <<  endl;

            return 0;
        }

};


 
 
// The cost and a distance for vector initialization

    extern "C" {
        AutoCorrect* AutoCorrect_new(){ return new AutoCorrect(); }
        void AutoCorrect_insert(AutoCorrect* autocorrect, char* word){ autocorrect->insert(word); }
        void AutoCorrect_search(AutoCorrect* autocorrect, string input_word){ autocorrect->search(input_word); }
        void AutoCorrect_test(AutoCorrect* autocorrect, char* name){ autocorrect-> test(name); }
    
    }
```

Python main.py:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('autocorrect.so')

class AutoCorrect(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.AutoCorrect_new()

    def insert(self, word):
        lib.AutoCorrect_insert(self.obj,word)
    
    def search(self,input_word):
        lib.AutoCorrect_search(self.obj,input_word)

    def test(self,test):
        lib.AutoCorrect_test(self.obj,test)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json
    WordCount = 0

    autocorrect = AutoCorrect()

    data_dir = "some_txt_file.txt"
autocorrect.insert(bytes(str(data_dir), encoding='utf8'))
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when running everything in C++ only?

Comment: `while(ifp >> word)` - is there any particular reason you are writing to the `char*` instead of having a separate `std::string` to read into. Writing to a `char*` of unknown bounds is very risky (and might very well be the cause of your problems)

Comment: @mch there was no error when running in C++, only when i tried to call it from python then it throw this error

Comment: @UnholySheep there was some error previously when i tried to use string, and the following error was thrown : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Comment: If you got that error with a `std::string` that only means that your use of `char*` is hiding it (and invoking *undefined behavior*) - so you should figure out why the `std::string` version wasn't working first

Comment: @UnholySheep alright, thanks so much for pointing that out, i will try to figure out why std::string wasnt working

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line you specified, i think there is an instance you are trying to add a value to a non existent key:

```
            if(children.count(remaining_w.at(0)) == 0){
            children[remaining_w.at(0)] = new trie();
```

if "children.count" returns 0 then that character is not present, then trying to add a value on the second line there means....

what i think you want to do on that line is:

```
            if(children.count(remaining_w.at(0)) == 1){
            children[remaining_w.at(0)] = new trie();
```

meaning you add the value only if key is present.

Comment: Hi Brian, i was trying to add a new Trie Node if the Trie tree doesn't contain an existing character

Comment: Hi John, yes, my bad it shouldn't  cause any memory problem on that line, that logic is correct

Comment: the memory problem only occur when i tried to call the C++ library from python, it doesnt happen for int or float data type though, only string